# DropboxSDK: error deleting credentials in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, warnings, dropbox-api

I am getting this warning while accessing Dropbox APIs in iOS.

```
[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error deleting credentials (-25300)
```

Someone can you please revert me your suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should correspond to errSecItemNotFound from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/errSecItemNotFound

Indicates the credentials you are trying to access does not exist.

Comment: But I can able to see that I have used all credentials properly (e.g. App key and App secret). What can I do so now? Previously Its was working fine into my app but from yesterday I am facing this issue.

Comment: Have you tried it on some other device? If its happening across devices please share the code snippet you are trying with

Comment: No, Its working on my other iPad and iPhone, but its not working into my iPad 64 bit device. It gives me error like : This URL is not valid. App secret may be incorrectly configured.

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version of the SDK (currently v1.3.13: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/ios ). It sounds like you may be encountering a bug on 64 bit devices that is fixed in updated versions of the SDK.

Comment: I am getting this error too. Situation: where my app is reinstalled and Dropbox was logged-in before uninstallation. If I force my app to log out after installation, this error is shown. Is that alright?